# API - HERE Routing - How to get miles driven per each state?

Tags: here-api

For any given route e.g. Brooklyn, NY to Seattle, WA, I need to calculate amount of miles we drove via each state.

I have tested multiple routing APIs and non of them return anything I could use in calculation. (I testes MapQuest, google and TomTom)
I spoke to HERE.com sales rep and he told me HERE-apis return that info but after running test calls it does not look to me that this is the case.

Does anyone know how to format query on HERE-api to get info I am looking for or any other way?

Comment: Hi , HERE Routing API does not support a feature to calculate to calculate the sum of amount miles grouping by State level. But probably you can do post process for the calculation the sum of amount miles based on road network in State level.

Answer (score 0):

HERE Routing API does not support a feature to calculate to calculate the sum of amount miles grouping by State level. But probably you can do post process for the calculation the sum of amount miles based on road network in State level.